# High CPU utilisation while using MQTT deamon..!

Tags: c++, multithreading, mqtt

I am using MQTT daemon in background to receive and send data to the server and this is a cyclic process so i have written the above functionality in thread(C++ & Qt) and the code is working fine.But the problem is it is consuming high CPU usage i.e min 91%-99% max,i have gone through my code several times but i was unable to spot the affecting area.

Please guide to find it,i was using Linux os with a kernel version 3.1

Thanks in advance,
Rohith.G

Comment: You have written *what* code? There is nothing for this question to be about yet.

Comment: The answer is on page 42.

Comment: If you want help with your code you are going to have to provide an [mcve]

Comment: To guide you about a code that We don't know anything ?

Comment: Sorry for not describing my issue so well,actually i am using MQTT protocol in my POS Device and when ever i run the program regarding MQTT it is showing the CPU usage is about 90-97%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT has a loop to check for messages. Please include a few micro second sleep. This reduces the high CPU usage drastically.

while True:
                        mqttc.loop_start()
                        time.sleep(0.001)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the CPU usage that was being used by mosquitto-deamon i have changed the keepalive value in the library source,it worked for me..!